# Razor form submit: database error ORA-01843: not a valid month only on chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, iis, razor-pages

I have a very strange bug on my asp.net 6 website. It is deployed on a IIS server.

When I use chrome to access the website on IIS and submit a form, it looks like chrome is .
The weird thing is that this bug occurs only with chrome executing the website on server.
I **don't have this bug on other browsers (firefox, edge) and above all I don't have this bug on debug local mode with any browser including chrome**. On consequence, I don't see what the incorrect date looks like before updating to oracle database on debug

```
<form method="post" id="formB" onsubmit="false" autocomplete="off">
  ... 
<button id="submit-btn" onclick="SubmitCheck()"> Confirm</button>
```

The bug occurs when there is no error in the form (I use js, jquery validation, asp props validation)

when the submit is triggered the OnPost method naturally executes, except with google chrome accessing the website hosted on an IIS server. Here is what my query looks like:

```cs
string queryPO = "UPDATE " +tablename+ " SET ... + ", OK_QUALITY = 
" + Chaine.DateInsert(PO.OK_quality) + ... + ", DATE_LAST_UPDATED = 
" + Chaine.DateInsert(System.DateTime.Now) + ..."

...
     
public static string DateInsert(DateTime? ndate)
{
   if (ndate == null) return "null";
   else return "to_date('" + ndate.ToString() + "','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS')";
}
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: What does the network tab in the browser developer tools show? And where is the code for the OnPost method?

Comment: found a cause: I have a database error : not a valid month ora-01843. Still: it works everywhere except on chrome on iis . I ll update my question